# How to compare value of cell with string variable?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
string findID = pacients.findByUniqueCode(code);

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
  {
     if ((string)row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == findID)
     {

     }
}
```

I get an error in line:

```
if ((string)row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == findID)
```

It can not convert `row.Cells` to string. How to fix it?

Comment: `Convert.ToString(row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to compare strings, both of your values has to be a strings which obliviously in your case is not a case!

So what you must do here to fix this is to convert your `row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value` to a string, and how to do that, depends of you, there are few ways but I will mention here two common ones,

you might do this by using build in `.ToString()` method, or you might use also build in `Convert.ToString()` method, it is up to you which you are going to choose, so you code might look like this:

```
if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value) == findID) 
{
   ....
}
```

or

```
if ((row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value).ToString() == findID)
{
   .....
}
```

Applying any of cases above should fix your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ToString?

```
if (row.Cells["idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() == findID)
```